# Best way to make a node.js file executable using nvm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I'm using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage my node versions. My node.js executable files used to be sha bang'ed like so `#! /usr/local/bin/node` but now it seems like I would have to do something like `#! /Users/<userName>/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/node` to accomplish the same thing.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: checkout this answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65235/universal-node-js-shebang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `#!/usr/bin/env node` in my node executable and it seems to work. There is a reference here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability

Comment: doesn't work for me (OS X El Capitan, nvm, node v7.7.0)

Comment: I ended up using `/usr/local/bin/node` after symlinking from nvm to that path